# how to convert time zone automatically

Tags: php

The date and time stored in my database is as:- 2017-01-11 10:01:55
 I want it to insert same as know but while displaying I want it to display as timezone like in India by Asia/Kolkata timezone 
 I have used

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata');
                $timestamp = date("Y-m-d h:m:i");
```

but it works in case of insert code not display and i don't want to mention which timezone can it be by default it automatically detect timezone and display  acoordingly
                please help
                 have tried this also

```
 date_default_timezone_set('UTC');



 no success
```

Comment: You can use javascript if you want to show in web. Store the data in database in UTC time and then get timezone of user like this `var d = new Date();
var timezone = d.getTimezoneOffset();`, Then change the date according to timezone check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10087819/convert-date-to-another-timezone-in-javascript#answer-18612568

Comment: please can send me the JS code that will be great m new in web development

Comment: Database dates don't have a "format" (unless you're doing it wrong and you're storing it as text). Key point is whether they have a time zone and that vastly depends on the DBMS you use. In any case I think you're confusing two entirely different issues: 1) How to manipulate dates in your app 2) Detect you user's time zone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just store your date in database UTC and then pass the date to the function it will return you the date in your timezone.

```js
$(function(){

  $('span.time').each(function(i, obj) {
     $(obj).text(convertDate($(obj).text()));
  });

});
function convertDate(givenDate){
    var myOldDateObj = new Date(givenDate);
    return myOldDateObj.toString();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<b>Inputs:</b>
<div>
2017-01-11T12:14:11<br/>
2017-01-10T12:14:11<br/><br/>
</div>
<b>Output:</b><br/>
<span class="time">2017-01-11T04:11:33</span><br/>
<span class="time">2017-01-10T12:14:11</span>
```

Comment: Change your system timezone and you can see it working.

Comment: My UTC date format is  2017-11-01UTC10:01:5510

and I don't want it by onclick I simply want to display according to users time zone Please Help @Aman

Comment: Changed the code. It will update all the time on load of the page.